# QProcess on MacOS trying to use diskutil

Tags: c++, macos, qt, terminal, qt5

Qt 5.12

I am trying to get the volume ID on macOS and using the following function:

```
QString getVolumeInfo()
{
    QString volumeID = "Cannot find the volumeID";
    QProcess p;
    //diskutil info $(df -h / | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1)
    QString command = "diskutil";
    QStringList args;
    args << "info" <<  "$(df -h / | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1)";
    p.start(command, args);
    p.waitForStarted();
    p.waitForFinished();
    foreach(QString line, QString(p.readAll()).split("\n"))
    {
       if(line.contains("Volume UUID:"))
           volumeID = line;
    }
    return volumeID;
}
```

I have to use the diskutil because of the limitation with macOS. However, QProcess, reading the object has nothing in it.

Command on terminal: **diskutil info $(df -h / | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1)**
which returns a ton of information like:

...

SMART Status: Verified

Volume UUID: 954BACF1-EBC5-4D14-86FB-0912CF7F839C

Disk / Partition UUID: 954BACF1-EBC5-4D14-86FB-0912CF7F839C

Disk Size: 500.1 GB (500068036608 Bytes) (exactly 976695384 512-Byte-Units)

....

When I try to add qDebug() to debug I get the following: true - "Could not find disk: $(df -h / | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1)\n"

So seem like the arguments is not formatted or something?

I am trying to implement: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50302/how-can-i-tell-which-volume-the-operating-system-is-on

Comment: The problem is that when you execute that command in your terminal the string `$(df -h / | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1)` is recognized by your shell and it executes those command for you and passes the resulting output as an argument to diskutil. QProcess is not a shell it just passes the string without any processing on to diskutil.

Comment: Got it... changed the process to: QStringList args;
    args << "-c" << "diskutil info $(df -h / | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1)";
    p.start("/bin/bash", args);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slight modification after Eelke explained.

```
QStringList args;
args << "-c" << "diskutil info $(df -h / | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1)";
p.start("/bin/bash", args);
```